# Pandas: Fill new column by condition row-wise

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.rand(100),100*[0.1],100*[0.3]]).T
df.columns = ["value","lower","upper"]

df.head()
```

[image]

How can I create a new column which indicates that `value` is between `lower` and `upper` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) for this purpose.

```
df['new_col'] = df['value'].between(df['lower'], df['upper'])
```

Comment: `df['new'] = ((df.value >= df.lower) & (df.value <= df.upper))` Another one.

Comment: I was actually aware of this one, but I always forget :( Thank you